# HTTP status code for "disabled temporarily"

Tags: http-status-codes

I would like to return a HTTP status code if signups for my site are currently disabled.

Would `503` work for this and/or is there a more appropriate code for this kind of request.

Answer (score 2):

`503` looks appropriate.

From Wikipedia:

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>       The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state.